# how to save doc and pdf file into mysql database from android application?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to send the doc and pdf file to the MySQL database using php from my android application.
I have no idea about it. What shoud i write in android and php file?

Please guide me if anyone have code?

Thanking you.

Comment: Have you thought about saving file in some folder and store in DB path to the file?

Comment: Have you thought about using google to ask that question?

Comment: No, i just want to select file into my app and send/save to MySQL databse. I have no idea about should i make folder for saving file or not?

Comment: u need to make folder and u just save the file name in the database. and when u select the file which u want to save u need to move the file to ur created folder. Like this i did it in php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Store it in a field with a [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html%E2%80%8E) data type. I really do not advise this in any way and is only listed as the first option because it pertains directly to your question.

SO has good coverage of this already [Storing files in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420305/storing-files-in-sql-server)

2) Move the file to a folder and store the file path. This is the preferred option by mmmm everyone. Use [move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) and if you are unsure of how to setup an html form take a look at [W3C PHP File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)