# Save from Windows forms to SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, sql-server-2014

I would like to know how to save a document(txt,pdf,doc,docx,xls etc) to Microsoft SQL Server using C# windows forms. Here's the form I've designed [File Upload Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQFXX.png). I've used the openfiledialog box but I couldn't select a file. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Also what kind of datatype should be used to save file in Microsoft SQL Server? Thanks!

```
OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Document";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == 
System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.Cursor = new Cursor(openFileDialog1.OpenFile());
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't select a file? What happened if you clicked on something? Also regarding the datatype to store it as in SQL, you can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420305/storing-files-in-sql-server

Comment: I got an error saying "Image format is not valid. The Image may be corrupted. Parameter name: Stream". I'm adding the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer below pointers and use it as per your requirement.

[Link1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/013102/save-and-read-pdf-file-using-sql-server-and-C-Sharp/)

[Link2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/save-pdf-file-in-sql-server-database-using-c-sharp1)

[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579373/saving-any-file-to-in-the-database-just-convert-it-to-a-byte-array)