# Can I store difference file types into SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a vb.net project and a SQL Server database, I want to store my other created projects to the database with some of there description. I don't know can I do that or I can store my projects files into the database in the first place. I wanted to compress my projects files to a zip file and then store the zip file to the database but I don't know if I can store these files to the database which includes a lot of file types like (jar, java, sln, vb, c#, txt ...etc)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should look into an existing version control solution, like git/github, svn, mercurial, etc

Comment: A database isn't a file system or blob container, and you're going to have a bad time if you try to use it as one. You should ask yourself what problem you think a database would solve for you -- it's almost certainly solved better by a good backup policy and/or source control.

Comment: Why are you storing *files* in a database?  (Hint: You *probably* shouldn't be.)  And, I guess more to the question... What's *stopping you* from storing files in a database?  When you look on Google for something like "store file in SQL Server", what do you find?  Cause I find this (among many other things): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420305/storing-files-in-sql-server  The file *type* doesn't really have anything to do with storing it.  So what have you tried and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I would not ignore these comments and actually **NOT** store files in your db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store files in a SQL Server database table. I highly recommend you to compress them into a zip file.

First step is to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Files
(
     Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     FileData VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM  NULL,
     Name NVARCHAR(300)
)
```

and then open your zip file as stream and Insert it into your table.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDlg.InitialDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

if (openFileDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(openFileDlg.FileName);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(fs);
    byte[] fileData = rdr.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    rdr.Close();
    fs.Close();

    string cs = @"Data Source=<your server>;Initial Catalog=MyFsDb;Integrated Security=TRUE";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        con.Open();
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Files VALUES (@Data, @Name)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Image, fileData.Length).Value = fileData;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = fi.Name;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    MessageBox.Show(fi.FullName, "File Inserted!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Source : [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2011/02/28/inserting-a-file-into-a-filestream-table-from-c-and-how-to-get-it-back-as-well/)

Comment: Thanks its what i need.