# Store File in Database Server as FILESTREAM

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, storage, sqlfilestream

I've used below link to create demo application to store files into database server as FILESTREAM, but in this **scenario Web server and database server are on same machine**. This is working as expected in local machine.
https://dba-presents.com/index.php/component/content/article?id=59:introduction-to-filestream

But, I want to store files into Database server as FILESTREAM while I am uploading from MVC application, **Where my database server and Web server are on different machine.** 
Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Comment: Can you post tried code?

Comment: I have followed same steps which are given in above link

Comment: I would suggest to store physical file on the Server and store the file path in to database!

Comment: Currently it is working as you suggest, but my client requirement is to store files on database server.

Comment: Ok, is it only images? or any types of files?

Comment: any types of files

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/8952/7124761 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420305/storing-files-in-sql-server