# How to get path directory of file when user selected in input type file

Tags: node.js

I wanna get location of file in my computer when I selected file in input type file. 
this is code in ejs file.

```
<html>
    <form name="insertData" method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="inputInsert" type="file" accept=".xlsx" name='filename'>
        <button class="insertButton">UPLOAD</button>
    </form>
</html>
```

For example: I selected file test.xlsx in my computer and I wanna send path of that file (C:/Users/HP/Desktop/test.xlsx) to controller. This is my code in controller.

```
exports.insertData = function(req,res) {
    var pathFile = //location of file that user selected
    res.render('home', {'path': pathFile})
}
```

I need to change location file as users selected file in thier computer. Thank you for help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot get the path of any local directory at server-side. So it has to be fetched at client side only.
Html Code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="inputInsert" type="file" accept=".xlsx" name="filename" id="fileUpload"/>
        <button class="insertButton">UPLOAD</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        $('#fileUpload').change(function (e) {
            console.log($(this).val()) // This will print out the file path
            console.log(e.target.files[0])
            /*
            The above line will print some more details about the file
            [object File]{
              arrayBuffer: function arrayBuffer() { [native code] },
              lastModified: 1589551849373,
              lastModifiedDate: [object Date] {
              $constructor: function Date() { [native code] },
                  $family: function(){return i}
                },
              name: "LoremIpsum.xlsx",
              size: 1205,
              slice: function slice() { [native code] },
              stream: function stream() { [native code] },
              text: function text() { [native code] },
              type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
              webkitRelativePath: ""
            }
            */
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are planning to upload your file at server-side, I think you should have a look at [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload)

Express.js Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const app = express();

// Default options applied currently. For more configuration go to express-fileupload link above
app.use(fileUpload());

exports.insertData = function(req,res) {
  // Ignore If you don't want to check if files were uploaded or not.
  if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
  }

  // The name of the input field (i.e. "filename") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
  let pathFile= req.files.filename;

  res.render("home", {"path": pathFile})
  });
});
```

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method is used to return an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly upon an object.

[Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) is also good for file uploading with express.js
**Note**: The modules mentioned is for [**express.js**](https://expressjs.com/)

Comment: Oh!! Thank you so much. I need to upload it into sql server database but now I can't do it. The file will upload is excel file

Comment: Storing file in database can create some [performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13421029/12082336). I would prefer storing them on server side into some directory and storing other details in database.