# How to store files effectively in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple question but i cannot find answers for

how to store files effectively in SQL server, these files could be pictures, word, excel or PowerPoint. I know how to store them the regular way by converting to bytes and so on but the real problem is that I am making a winforms application for teachers and they should store some files in the DB, my online DB size could be like 3 GB and if every teacher store 50 files * 5 MB it will consume the DB size in one minute.

So... How to store them in less size and more efficient way. Also is that mean if i uploaded 5 MB word file will it be stored as 5 MB size in DB?

Knowing that i am using C#

Comment: this might helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420305/storing-files-in-sql-server

Comment: I do read all of this but this is not the answer needed for my question, Thanks guys.